# How can I import static HTML into my ESM code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application. This app uses Axios, and Axios is configured outside the React component tree. Thus Axios only works in the plain ESM environment.

When I receive 403 from API, I want to show a 403 page explaining to the user that they do not have access to this part of the app.

I want to do something like `document.body.innerHTML = "You are not authorized to see this section".

This works, but this is very hard to maintain. Because I want to create a complex HTML with links to other places and detailed explanation and a default styling.

Is it possible to create an static HTML page, and import it from my `Axios.jsx` file?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

You can use [renderToStaticMarkup](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToStaticMarkup) to compile your JSX into HTML.

This makes it extremely easy. I create my HTML as a simple JSX and export it from the other file and import it in my Axios config file, and compile it to HTML string.